# Scrapy: How do I yield items in the same dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am pretty new to Scrapy. I wrote a program that scrapes different information about movies from a main website. However, to get all the information I have to yield items from multiple sites and I wrote 2 other functions besides "parse".

The problem is that I want the items to be in the same dictionary for each movie so as to be stored in a CSV file. Now, the values from the first function are returned first in a dictionary, and the values from the second one separately.

These are the functions:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        items = LetterboxdItem()
        all_li_films = response.css('li.poster-container')
        for films in all_li_films:
            film_link = films.css(...).extract()

            yield from response.follow_all(film_link, self.parse_film)


    def parse_film(self, response):
        items = LetterboxdItem()

        film_title = response.css(...).extract()
        film_director = response.css(...).extract()
        film_year = response.css(...).extract()

        film_rating_link = response.css(...).extract()

        items['film_director'] = film_director
        items['film_title'] = film_title
        items['film_year'] = film_year

        yield items
        yield response.follow(film_rating_link,self.parse_rating)

    def parse_rating(self, response):
        items = LetterboxdItem()
        film_rating = response.css(...).extract()

        items['film_rating'] = film_rating
        yield items
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but you have two `yield` statements in `parse_film(...)` - this is certainly not intended, is it?

Comment: @Jan. Op is trying to load ratings from `film_rating_link` (another page) so I assume it's intended

Comment: yes, it is intended

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow. You could try to use `cb_kwargs` and pass `items` to that (and obv remove the first yield). I haven't tested it though, just a suggestion.